# Does integrating over an interval/set have a different meaning?

Tags: integration, notation

I have seen integrals written like $\int_{(0,\pi)} \sin xdx$ instead of $\int^\pi_0 \sin x dx$. Are these the same thing, or does the former refer to something entirely different? I have recently been writing things like $\int_\mathbb{R} xe^{-x^2}dx=0$, short for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$ but I am unsure whether these are misleading rather than convenient.

Answer (score 2):

At a simple level, the main difference is that you can write $\int_\pi^0\sin xdx=-\int_0^\pi\sin xdx$, but you can't reverse the direction of the input in $\int_{(0,\pi)}\sin xdx$ since the input is not directed there.

So you can think of something like $\int_{(a,b)}f(x)dx$ as the difference between (the area bounded by the graph of $f$ above the interval $(a,b)$ on the $x$-axis) and (the area below $(a,b)$). But $\int_b^af(x)dx=-\int_{(a,b)}f(x)dx$ when $a<b$.

There is more that can be said, especially when generalizing to more advanced things like multivariable calculus and differential geometry. Terry Tao touches upon this distinction in the beginning of [his preprint introduction to differential forms](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/forms.pdf).